# mysql filter with dynamic json key

Tags: mysql, json

I need to select SUM of all value which is realized (=true) from the mysql data set below. In this example, I should get 1000 only.

Please note that the key is dynamic (year\month\day).

I am able to get a list of value by running the sql below:

```
SELECT (JSON_EXTRACT(json_value, "$**.value")) AS total FROM milestone
```

However, i can't seem to get the filter part works with this:

```
JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(json_value, 'all', "$**.realized") IS NOT NULL
```

id=1, column json_value

```
{
  "2018": {
    "5": {
      "4": {
        "value": "5000"
      }
    },
    "12": {
      "4": {
        "value": "80000",
        "realized": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

id=2, column json_value

```
{
  "2016": {
    "12": {
      "4": {
        "value": "1000",
        "realized": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern versions of MySQL (>= 8.0.4) the query would be relatively simple (see [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table)):

```sql
SELECT
  `milestone`.`id`,
  SUM(`der`.`value`) `total`
FROM
  `milestone`,
  JSON_TABLE(
    JSON_ARRAY(`json_value`),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS(
      NESTED PATH '$**.*' COLUMNS(
        `value` DECIMAL(10, 2) PATH '$.value',
        `realized` VARCHAR(5) PATH '$.realized'
      )
    )
  ) `der`
WHERE
  `der`.`value` IS NOT NULL AND
  `der`.`realized` = 'true'
GROUP BY
  `milestone`.`id`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cHM87AiUmqfdaH8Y9BCqun/1).

Comment: but i am on mariadb 10.2

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that works on MySQL 5.7:

```
SELECT SUM(
  JSON_UNQUOTE(
    JSON_EXTRACT(
      json_value,
      CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_value, 'all', 'true')), '.', 4),
        '.value'
      )
    )
  )
) AS sum
FROM milestone 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_value, 'all', 'true')),
  '.', -1) = 'realized'
```

This is quite complex, and hard to develop and maintain. Also it might not handle cases where you have multiple `realized: true` entries in a given JSON document. Or if there are other JSON keys besides "realized" that have the value "true". It will be quite tricky to even think of the edge cases, let alone handle them in code.

Out of curiosity, why not store this data as a traditional table?

```
CREATE TABLE milestone (
  milestone_id INT NOT NULL,
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  value INT NOT NULL,
  realized BOOL,
  PRIMARY KEY (milestone_id, date)
);

INSERT INTO milestone VALUES
(1, '2018-05-04',  5000, NULL),
(1, '2018-12-04', 80000, false),
(2, '2016-12-04',  1000, true);
```

Then it's simpler to do your query:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM milestone WHERE realized = true;
```

I'm curious because I'm seeing more people using JSON in MySQL for cases where it would be easier to use normal tables and column. Easier to write the query, easier to understand the query, and more efficient to store the data and optimize the query performance.

Using JSON in the way you are doing makes queries more difficult than they should be.

Comment: Yes, I admit it is very complex. Decided to do it this way because the requirements was unclear and I wanted the greatest flexibility. So I can have different type of milestone in one table and have different format of value in json form. 

When I have time I can run some cron script to create temporary traditional view table of these json, like what you stated, is more easier and optimize when query, mainly for reporting purposes. But now I just need a quick and fast method to get it works. Many thanks for the query, it works with MariaDb10.2 where my database is hosted at AWS RDS.

Comment: Getting the requirements clarified before coding a solution is less expensive than implementing such a complex and difficult solution. You'll just have to redesign the implementation and migrate data from the JSON solution to the new solution, which will be more work. You should focus on getting requirements before starting to implement the database.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of your reasons. I'm designing a presentation for Oracle OpenWorld, "How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong"